# XSLT 3: xsl:analyze-string of empty nodeset does not execute xsl:non-matching-substring

Tags: xslt-3.0

I'm using `xsl:analyze-string` to parse text inside a node that may be inexistant.

```xml
<xsl:analyze-string select="inexistant" regex="^([0-9]+)$">
```

According to [XSLT 3.0](https://www.w3.org/TR/xslt-30/#analyze-string):

> If the result of evaluating the select expression is an empty
> sequence, it is treated as a zero-length string.

I expect analyze-string to find that an empty string doesn't match my regex, and thus   `xsl:non-matching-substring` to be executed. But that doesn't actually happen: instead, analyze-string doesn't produce anything.

I'm using Saxon 9.9.1.7 within Oxygen-XML. [Saxonica's analyze-string documentation](https://www.saxonica.com/html/documentation/xsl-elements/analyze-string.html) isn't specific about selecting an empty nodeset.

[XSLT Fiddle here](https://xsltfiddle.liberty-development.net/93nwMoq/2) showing:

- the problem: I expect the `empty-select` element to contain the text "not matched"
- a workaround: prepending the tested string and the regex with "x" so that analyze-string gets a non-empty string. Not elegant.

Question: is it a bug in Saxon 9 or am I misunderstanding XSLT 3.0 specification?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think Saxon is behaving as specified in the section:

> The processor starts by setting the current position to position zero,
> and the current non-matching substring to a zero-length string

and

> If there is no match:
>
> If the current position is the last position (that is, just after the
> last character):
>
> If the current non-matching substring has length greater than zero,
> evaluate the xsl:non-matching-substring sequence constructor with the
> current non-matching substring as the context item.
>
> Exit.

So you are right that the empty sequence is treated as a zero length string but as a zero length string doesn't produce any non-matching substring the `xsl:non-matching-substring` is not evaluated.

The test case https://github.com/w3c/xslt30-test/blob/master/tests/insn/analyze-string/analyze-string-035.xsl is in the test suite to check that, doing

```xml
    <xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" version="3.0">
    
      <!-- PURPOSE: test xsl:analyze-string applied to an empty sequence - error in 2.0, treated as "" in 2.1. -->
      
      <xsl:param name="in" select="()"/>
    
      <xsl:template match="/">
        <out>
          <xsl:analyze-string select="$in" regex="[A-Z]">
           <xsl:matching-substring><m/></xsl:matching-substring>
           <xsl:non-matching-substring><n/></xsl:non-matching-substring>
          </xsl:analyze-string>      
        </out>
      </xsl:template>
      
    
    </xsl:stylesheet>
```

it is supposed (https://github.com/w3c/xslt30-test/blob/master/tests/insn/analyze-string/_analyze-string-test-set.xml#L288) to produce the result `<out/>`.

As you are using XSLT 3 anyway, you might want to see whether the `analyze-string` function is an alternative as you could do e.g. `let $analyze-result := analyze-string(inexistant, '^([0-9]+)$') return if (not($analyze-result/*)) then (: handle nor match nor non-match here :) else ...`.

Comment: Thanks, I assumed that an empty string would be non-matching, but in fact this algorithm in the specs makes it neither matching nor non-matching. Might be useful one day!